# Z.EntityFramework.Plus MemberInitExpression error

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am getting the following error using

```
System.Exception: Invalid Cast. The update expression must be of type MemberInitExpression. at Z.EntityFramework.Plus.BatchUpdate.ResolveUpdateFromQueryDictValues[T](Expression`1 updateFactory)
```

And this is what I am doing:

```
    public void Update(Expression<Func<CustomerConsentEntity, bool>> expression, CustomerConsentEntity entity)
    {
        DbContext.CustomerConsents.Where(expression).Update(x => entity);
    }

    public void Update(Expression<Func<CustomerConsentEntity, bool>> expression, CustomerConsentEntity entity)
    {
        DbContext.CustomerConsents.Where(a => a.TrackingId == Guid.Parse("4D8214D5-3D43-4A3E-9572-BCDCEA6F3BF9")).Update(x => entity);
    }

    public void Update(Expression<Func<CustomerConsentEntity, bool>> expression, CustomerConsentEntity entity)
    {
        Expression<Func<CustomerConsentEntity, CustomerConsentEntity>> updateEntity = x => entity;

        DbContext.CustomerConsents.Where(expression).Update(updateEntity);
    }
```

I am using the Z.EntityFramework.Plus and have done this a couple of times, but this time it seems to be failing for some strange reason. I have tried a couple of different ways while keeping the signature simple but they alll fail.

This works but it's not ideal:

```
        public void Update(Expression<Func<CustomerConsentEntity, bool>> expression, Expression<Func<CustomerConsentEntity, CustomerConsentEntity>> updateExpression)
    {
        DbContext.CustomerConsents.Where(expression).Update(updateExpression);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I found to get this working properly is to build [Member init expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression.memberinit?view=net-5.0) and pass it as a parameter to the **Update** function instead of *Expression<Func>*.

**PS**

The entire syntax for building expression trees made this method parametrization too complex for maintenance so at some point I decided to discard it and just build multiple methods with precompiled expressions.